# How can I wrap long text labels with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, text, word-wrap

I have created a `node-tree` using `D3` and would like to understand how to wrap texts that are too long.

```
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        if(d.name == "root"){
            return "";
        } else {
            return d.name;
        }
       })
      .style("font-family", "Verdana")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

If d.name is too long I'd like it to fill several lines instead of one. I have found this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321 but I do not seem to understand how this works, and I certainly don't understand how the "wrap" function gets it's input? On this example the wrap function has no parameters when called.

Comment: Well just call `wrap(d.name, <width>)`.

Comment: I tried doing so, but I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", I can only succesfully call it by doing ".call(wrap, [width])", and I've figured out getting the data right. I have received my text in the function now, and in the example they retrieve a "Y" attribute from the text. I don't have such attribute, I only have a dy set for my text. Can you understand why the Y attribute is needed and how it works?

Comment: And when attempting to "append("tspan") I get undefined error aswell. I cannot append to it.

Answer (score 3):

The code from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321 has two key parts.

The call to **wrap()** done

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
```

which is expecting a text element and a width like done in

```
node.append("text")
  // Make sure to have a text element
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .call(wrap, 50);
```

The confusing part here is that call statements apply to the current selection like `.tick text` or all nodes.

The second part is the required `text.text()` otherwise it does not work.

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
  var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
```